# Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /listings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permission-denied

I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. Paperclip with S3.

Errno::EACCES in ListingsController#update
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /listings
Extracted source (around line #44):

42. def update
43. respond_to do |format|
44. if @listing.update(listing_params)
45. format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was 46.successfully updated.' }
46. format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @listing }
    48      else

Listing_controller.rb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
    <p><%= number_to_currency (@listing.price) %></p>
    <p><%= @listing.description %></p>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-link" %>
<%= link_to 'Back', listings_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

In model,

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb =>        "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

In views, show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
    <p><%= number_to_currency (@listing.price) %></p>
    <p><%= @listing.description %></p>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-link" %>
<%= link_to 'Back', listings_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

Gems installed,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.3.3"

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem "paperclip", git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'listen', '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'aws-sdk'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Error within Terminal,

```
Listing Load (5.7ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE      "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
[paperclip] Trying to link   /var/folders/__/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/RackMultipart20170210-    36927-1iuewku.jpg to  /var/folders/__/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg
```

[paperclip] Trying to link /var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg to /var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1t9j57i.jpg
    Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1t9j57i.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg[0]'
    Command :: convert '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "200" '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/73570fb1d3ecfa0dc9a9d5e124c5763420170210-36927-j452kb'
    [paperclip] Trying to link /var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/73570fb1d3ecfa0dc9a9d5e124  c5763420170210-36927-j452kb to /var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/9918700e8a5840d631b32dff0efdc32820170210-36927-1j9zu6h
    Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg[0]'
    Command :: convert '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/73570fb1d3ecfa0dc9a9d5e124c5763420170210-36927-1t64b8q'
    [paperclip] Trying to link /var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/73570fb1d3ecfa0dc9a9d5e124c5763420170210-36927-1t64b8q to /var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/5a42e5f066b94471d8d7dd70241f775820170210-36927-1l2vm2j
    [paperclip] Trying to link /var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-1ywsn2q.jpg to /var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-h40oj7.jpg
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/**/2162ls5577704gd514y0859w0000gp/T/c3e768b17c5aa48db8ffbc959904bbaa20170210-36927-h40oj7.jpg'
    SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "listings" SET "image_file_name" = ?, "image_file_size" = ?, "image_updated_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "listings"."id" = ?  [["image_file_name", "022916_flyMG2.jpg"], ["image_file_size", 12403], ["image_updated_at", 2017-02-10 01:24:57 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-02-10 01:24:58 UTC], ["id", 1]]                           (1.0ms) rollback transaction
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 457ms (ActiveRecord: 8.6ms)

```
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /listings):

app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:43:in `update'
  Rendering /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-  5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erbwithin rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack- 5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (7.4ms)
  Rendering /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendering /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (152.5ms)
```

Comment: Permission denied means permission denied. Check that you can create directories in that location as the user you're connecting as. My guess is you're inadvertently trying to create a root-level directory.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Figure out where the `/listings` directory is specified. This is usually in the Paperclip initializer.

Comment: This is my linitializer for paperclip.rb..am i missing something?
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':joeget.s3.amazonaws.com'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tadman said, you are trying to create your attachments outside your application path.

Try changing

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

with something like

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ':rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

or

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = "#{Rails.root}/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. You guys are life savers. Would you know why its showing a broken image now when i upload?

Comment: Without more info, I think that it is related to `default_options[:url]` where you are telling paperclip to use an S3 url but it looks like paperclip is not configured to save the attachments in the cloud

Comment: Here is the error on my picture. 
No route matches [GET] "/images/:joeget.s3.amazonaws.com"

Rails.root: /Users/chris/Joeget

Comment: based on the error, you are not using S3 properly, what if you just comment or delete you paperclip initializer?

Comment: When i delete it my images show up after upload, but are local not on s3.

Comment: Follow a tutorial about how to integrate paperclip with s3: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3

Comment: Will do. When putting the code in the dev.rb do I just place it at the bottom of the page?

Comment: It can be in any place between `Rails.application.configure do` block

Comment: I am confused at where I put the code for  AWS permissions on the last step after making an aws.yml file under /config.

Comment: It should be set in AWS site in the bucket properties

Comment: This is how to put it in correct? I checked over it a lot and it looks right to me.
Invalid principal in policy - "AWS" : "(arn:aws:iam::85295303273:user/joeget)"